# Finding the formula for nth term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recursion

I have the following recursive sequence an i want to find the general formula for the nth term of a sequence:

$$a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}+4a_n,a_1=1,a_2=2$$

I have the following characteristic equation:
$x^2=4x+4$ but this has no integer zeroes so i do not know how to proceed with this.

Comment: $x^2-4x-4=0$ has no integer solutions, but it does have solutions...

Comment: I know but this should be solvable without a calculator and number are strange when it comes to this equation

Comment: The above quadratic equation *is* solvable without a calculator...were you able to find those solutions?

Comment: Quadratic equations are almost always solvable without the calculator.

Comment: $2 + 2\sqrt{2}$ and $2-2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: but to raise this to the 3rd or 4th power then the numbers are huge

Comment: Well, this sequence *does* get fast pretty quickly, so that would be expected. Then again, are you sure you'll need to raise anything to the third power or higher in this problem?

Comment: becouse if i want to find general formula i would do it like that $a_n=A(2+\sqrt{2})^n+B(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ and i would do this with $a_n$ for $n\in{3,4}$ am i right? I wrong please tell me how to do this

Comment: Why not do it with $n=1,2$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

there exists universal method of solving linear recurrences

for example in these topics

[Linear Homogeneous Recurrence Relations and Inhomogenous Recurrence Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734276/linear-homogeneous-recurrence-relations-and-inhomogenous-recurrence-relations)

[solving recurrence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117633/solving-recurrence-relations?rq=1)

[Solving a Linear Recurrence Relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734331/solving-a-linear-recurrence-relation?rq=1)

it was described.

it is also in Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

or just google for "solving linear recurrence relations" or "solving homogeneous linear recurrence relations"

Answer (score 0):

since the constants are chosen so that the surds always cancel, we can use the binomial theorem to obtain for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
a_{n+1} = 2^n \sum_{0 \le 2k \le n} \binom{n}{2k} 2^k
$$